# Android: Loading bitmap to dynamic view

Tags: java, android, multithreading, bitmap, android-asynctask

I'm relatively new to Android, and working on an app that will load bitmaps into a dynamically created layout with an ImageView. The number of layouts and ImageViews is based on some dynamic data (i.e. an API call). I want to load Bitmaps into these ImageViews after they have been dynamically created and add them to the main layout. Since I will be creating multiple dynamic layouts and loading multiple bitmaps this can't be done synchronously on the main thread. I'm currently using a solution based on AsyncTasks but I'm thinking there might be a more efficient method (possibly using Handler/Runnable).

Currently, I have implemented a solution that uses AsyncTasks in the following way:

1) Launch the first AsyncTask from the main thread

```
for(Event event : events.getEventList()) {
  // Create an UpdateCalendarUITask to update the UI
  CalendarUpdateTask calendarTask = new CalendarUpdateTask(this, parentView);
  calendarTask.execute(event);
}
```

2) Create and populate the layout (adding Text and Image views), add the newly created dynamic view to the layout, and call back to the main thread on completion (using an interface).

```
public class CalendarUpdateTask extends AsyncTask<Event, Void, RelativeLayout> {

  private final WeakReference<Activity> activityReference;
  private final WeakReference<ViewGroup> parentViewReference;
  ....
  public CalendarUpdateTask(Context context, ViewGroup parentView) {
    parentViewReference = new WeakReference<ViewGroup>(parentView);
    activityReference = new WeakReference<Activity>((Activity) context);
  }

  @Override
  protected RelativeLayout doInBackground(Event... params) {
    myEvent = params[0];
    return updateGameView(myEvent); // returns created RelativeLayout
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(RelativeLayout result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    // Add the Game/Event view to the Events View
    if( // Reference and nulls checks ) {
        ViewGroup parentView = parentViewReference.get();            
        parentView.addView(result);
        TaskListener listener = (TaskListener) activityReference.get();
        listener.loadImages(myEvent);
    }
  }
  ....    
}
```

3) The listener function loadImages(...) launches another AsyncTask that loads the bitmaps (similar to [this](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html))

This works ok. However, it is still a little slow loading lots of images because bitmaps aren't loaded until after the views is created. I can't call it before because I don't have a reference to the ImageView until after it is created. I can't launch the second AsyncTask from CalendarUpdateTask because it must always be launched from the main thread.

Ideally I would prefer to launch both operations at the same time and have a callback that is notified once both operations are done so that the bitmap can be loaded into the new ImageView.

There has to be a better option correct? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use something like a `ListView` or `GridView` with an `Adapter` to track your data objects.  These built-in classes automatically manage what is visible and not and will request you to provide a view when needed.  That is when you should create your `ImageView` instances.  Loading the images is another story which you'll want to be careful about as it is possible for the holding view to be destroyed between the time you start to load the image and the time it finishes.

Comment: Yeah I had looked into ListView and I think this is another possible solution. I think I would need a ListView with a custom object though because I'm essentially inserting a bunch of RelativeLayouts (with multiple Text and Image views) into a ScrollView. Do you happen to have an example of how to do that?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a ready-made example I can share.  Use XML layouts and an adapter, possibly a Loader to fetch the images themselves.  Look for some of the GoogleIO talks on <code>Adapter</code> or other resources, there are plenty out there.

Comment: After looking into this utilizing a ListView with a custom layout for each "Item" View is what I'm using. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If your need is only to load images from server to a particular view than there are different libraries to to do that:

1. Universal image loader.
2. Google Volley

These libs will ask for the URL and View to which this bitmap will be loaded and they also provide listners at different point of image loading.
These libs can also cache them on disk so that application don't fetch them again and again. and will create a Hashmap with key as URL of the image and Value as Bitmap.

Using AsyncTask is not a good approach for this particular case in my way because even if they run on background thread but multiple AsyncTask will run one by one i.e Synchronously.

So if you want to just load images this will be a good approach.

If you have any query feel free to ask.

Comment: The images I'm loading are actually stored in my drawable folder, but I don't know which images to load until after my connection to the server. I'm not sure if those libraries are overkill.

AsyncTask can be run in parallel with the executeOnExecutor and a ThreadPoolExecutor?

Comment: Yes, you can adjust how AsyncTasks get executed using the ThreadPoolExecutor.